# Networkx: How to find all unique paths of max given length in an unweighted, undirected, unlabeled, connected graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, enumeration

Let's say I have the following unweighted (all edges weight = 1), undirected, unlabeled, connected graph and I want to **find all unique paths of maximum given length**. Also, nodes cannot appear twice in a path. I cannot find a routine that does this in networkx atm.

Does anyone knows if any such thing exists ?
Or what could be a good solution for this problem ?

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 4), (6, 9), (8, 9), (9, 6)])
```

The exemple graph looks like this

[image]

Let's say I require max length = 2, I would like this output

```
[1 2]
[2 3]
[2 4]
[3 4]
[4 5]
[5 6]
[6 7]
[7 8]
[8 9]
[6 9]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[2 3 4]
[2 4 5]
[3 4 5]
[4 5 6]
[5 6 7]
[5 6 9]
[6 7 9]
[6 7 8]
[7 8 9]
[6 9 8]
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a better solution than using itertools to generate all nodes combinations of required_max_path_length-1 number of nodes + checking for connectivity using G.has_edge(node_1, node_2) within the combinations groups or something similar, which seems like a super bad solution.

Comment: What about paths that are less than 2?

Comment: It's also required, I'm editing my example thanks

Comment: Look at `all_simple_paths`.  It lets you specify a cutoff.  It still would be n^2 since you need to specify every start and end node

Comment: I was thinking about `all_simple_paths` but having to specify start and end node made me think it's a bad solution. But you are saying use `itertools` to get all  pairwise nodes combinations + `all_simple_paths` between each of these nodes combinations at maximum length cutoff + filter all generated paths for uniqueness, right ? It would work I guess, but I'm still wondering if there could be a better solution.

Comment: You shouldn't need itertools.

Comment: So just classic python loops for node pairs generation, also works right with one less library to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So now I'm doing this thx to @user3483203 and it yields the expected output. Itertools usage can be avoided but I don't mind in my specific case.

I still feel like it would scale a bit worst than something else for larger graphs though, I will change the accepted answer if someone finds a better solution.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

required_max_path_length = 2 # (inferior or equal to)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (2, 4), (6, 9), (8, 9), (9, 6)])

all_paths = []
nodes_combs = itertools.combinations(G.nodes, 2)

for source, target in nodes_combs:
    paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target, cutoff=required_max_path_length)

    for path in paths:
        if path not in all_paths and path[::-1] not in all_paths:
            all_paths.append(path)

for path in all_paths:
    print(path)
```

In case you want the paths as lists of edges you can do:

```
for path in map(nx.utils.pairwise, all_paths):
    print(list(path))
```

And you will get:

```
[(1, 2)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 4)]
[(2, 3)]
[(2, 3), (3, 4)]
[(2, 4)]
[(2, 4), (4, 5)]
[(3, 4)]
[(3, 4), (4, 5)]
[(4, 5)]
[(4, 5), (5, 6)]
[(5, 6)]
[(5, 6), (6, 7)]
[(5, 6), (6, 9)]
[(6, 7)]
[(6, 7), (7, 8)]
[(6, 8), (8, 9)]
[(6, 9)]
[(7, 8)]
[(6, 7), (7, 9)]
[(7, 8), (8, 9)]
[(8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your task, but it outputs more paths than you have given (e.g. `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`):

```py
def find_all_simple_paths(graph, cutoff):

    if cutoff == 0:
        return [[node] for node in graph]
    else:
        all_paths = []
        current_paths = [[node] for node in graph]
        # If you want to include paths of length 0
        # all_paths.extend(current_paths)
        for _ in range(min(cutoff, len(graph))):
            next_paths = []
            for path in current_paths:
                #print(path)
                for neighbor in graph.neighbors(path[-1]):
                    if neighbor not in path:
                        new_path = path[:] + [neighbor]
                        next_paths.append(new_path)
                        all_paths.append(new_path)
            current_paths = next_paths

        return all_paths
find_all_simple_paths(G,2)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2],
 [2, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 2],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [4, 2],
 [5, 4],
 [5, 6],
 [6, 5],
 [6, 7],
 [6, 9],
 [7, 6],
 [7, 8],
 [8, 7],
 [8, 9],
 [9, 6],
 [9, 8],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 3],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [3, 2, 1],
 [3, 2, 4],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 2],
 [4, 3, 2],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 2, 1],
 [4, 2, 3],
 [5, 4, 3],
 [5, 4, 2],
 [5, 6, 7],
 [5, 6, 9],
 [6, 5, 4],
 [6, 7, 8],
 [6, 9, 8],
 [7, 6, 5],
 [7, 6, 9],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [8, 7, 6],
 [8, 9, 6],
 [9, 6, 5],
 [9, 6, 7],
 [9, 8, 7]]
```